# data provider with arraylist of array in Test NG

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have to send a array list of arrays to the test case using the dataprovider annotation. I have the below code but it is giving illegal argument exception. My arraylist size is 4096. Do I need to give such many arguments in test method.

```
 @Test(dataProvider="combination_list")
 public void checkbox_combination(List<int[]> obj) {


    /*for(int i=0;i<=4095;i++) {

    }*/
}
@DataProvider(name="combination_list")
public static Object[][] get_Combination_list() {

    List<int[]>  combinations_with_int_array = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    int size_combination;

    for(int i=0;i<=4095;i++) {

        String checkbox_combination =Combination_List.intToString(i,12);

        int[] single_combination = new int[12];

        for (int j=0;j<=11;j++) {

            if(j<11)
            {

                single_combination[j]=Integer.parseInt(checkbox_combination.substring(j, j+1));

            }
            else
            {
                single_combination[j]=Integer.parseInt(checkbox_combination.substring(j));

            }
        }
        combinations_with_int_array.add(single_combination);

    }
    size_combination=combinations_with_int_array.size();

    System.out.println("No of combinations : "+size_combination);

    Object  objArray[][] = new Object[size_combination][];

    for(int i=0;i<size_combination;i++){

        objArray[i] = new Object[1];

        objArray[i][0] = combinations_with_int_array.get(i);
    } 
    return objArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception? It may provide more data. From what you posted so far I'd suspect that int[] and Object[] are incompatible.

Comment: [ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR] com.mavenReports.xsltr.MavenDemo.checkbox_combination(com.mavenReports.xsltr.MavenDemo)
[ERROR]   Run 1: MavenDemo.checkbox_combination » IllegalArgument argument type mismatch
[ERROR]   Run 2: MavenDemo.checkbox_combination » IllegalArgument argument type mismatch
[ERROR]   Run 3: MavenDemo.checkbox_combination » IllegalArgument argument type mismatch
[ERROR]   Run 4: MavenDemo.checkbox_combination » IllegalArgument argument type mismatch

Comment: Perhaps it's because you used the symbol "checkbox_combination" in two different meanings in your code? Is it a string or a class that gets list of arrays?

Comment: checkbox_combination it is test method name and my mistake I have used the same keyword as String also. But since string variable is local to the method it will not affect I feel. I have changed the test method argument from List<int []> to Object  and it is working fine. Thanks Assafs your comment helped. But can you help me how to access the list in the object argument of test method.

Comment: Sorry, that was as far as I could go. Glad I helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combinations_with_int_array is an arrayList of int[].

```
objArray[i][0] = combinations_with_int_array.get(i);
```

When you do a get on the list, it give you int[] which is the type of the argument, which it is adding to the Object[][].  So your test method should have the same argument.